# How do "environment variables" work when executing them in the same line with a command?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, command

I can supply an environment variable to a Python script and immediately print it with:

```
$ FOO="bar" python -c "import os; print(os.environ.get('FOO'))"
bar
```

However the same does not work with `echo`:

```
$ FOO="bar" echo $FOO
 
$ echo $PWD
/home/nntin
```

**First question**: How come it did not print `bar`?

---

When running multiple commands the environment variable is only applied to the first command.

```
$ FOO="bar" python -c "import os; print(os.environ.get('FOO'))" && python -c "import os; print(os.environ.get('FOO'))"
bar
None
```

I could solve it with:

```
$ FOO="bar" python -c "import os; print(os.environ.get('FOO'))" && FOO="bar" python -c "import os; print(os.environ.get('FOO'))"
bar
bar
```

but it gets clunky fast when I am passing a lot of environment variables.

**Second question**: How can I apply it to both? I want to execute two commands one after another with e.g. `&&` but I only want to define the environment variable once in the command line and not twice.

**I prefer setting the environment variables within the same command line** because the environment variables may change and it is easier for me to execute a single line of command then multiple commands sequentially. I would prefer if I only need to change a single value.

PS:
Excuse me for the confusing title. I didn't know what it is called and where to search it under. When I execute my code like this the environment variable is not permanently set as in the next command line does not have that environment variable. But within the code it acts like a set environment variable.
Feel free to change the title and description.

Comment: See also [Set environment variable for subshell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392050/set-environment-variable-for-subshell) for details about how to set an environment variable for something like `cmd1 && cmd2`

Comment: Thank you @satwell !

Answer (score 0):

In the first example:

The command line is evaluated, the value 'bar' is loaded into the environment variable 'FOO' and the python code is executed, which evaluates the environment variable 'FOO' and prints its contents: 'bar'

The second example: The command line is eavluated, the value 'bar' is loaded into the variable 'FOO' but `echo $FOO` is evaluated simultaneously and $FOO *has not yet been loaded*, so it echoes the empty string.

In your third example, `&&` separates two commands and adhoc environment variables aren't carried over. You could get away with

`FOO='bar' ( python -c "import os; print(os.environ.get('FOO'))" && FOO="bar" python -c "import os; print(os.environ.get('FOO'))"  )`

Comment: The command you supplied is not a valid command. It prints the error `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('`. I did say in my question that I could write `FOO="bar"` twice but it wouldn't be ideal for me.